# Reconocer la Ñ en una cadena de caracteres

Tags: python, python-2.x

Reconocer si Ñ en una cadena de caracteres.

```
cadena = "DADEVVEÑWE"
```

Si yo hago:

```
for letra in cadena:
    if letra == 'D':
        print 'Letra D'
    elif letra == 'Ñ':
        print 'Letra Ñ'
```

¿Por qué las Ñ se las salta y no las ve? Y el resto de letras si que las ve (si pongo su correspondiente condicional). ¿Donde le aplico la codificación para que reconzca las Ñ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se debe a la forma en que Python 2 trabaja con los caracteres no-ascii.

Resulta que cuando tú pones en tu código fuente una línea como esta:

```
cadena = "EÑE"
```

lo que realmente va a parar a la variable depende de qué editor hayas usado.

Si usas un editor que usa codificación ISO (por ejemplo, muchos editores de windows), se guardarán en la variable tres bytes, pues en esa codificación cada letra es un solo byte (y el código de la letra `Ñ` sería `f1`).

Si usas un editor que usa codificación UTF-8 (lo más estándar hoy día, en linux y en mac e incluso en windows según que editor uses), entonces en la variable irían cuatro bytes, pues en esa codificación algunas letras ocupan sólo un byte (las ascii) y otras dos ó tres. La eñe en particular se codificaría con dos bytes  de valor `c3` y `91`.

Esto trae todo tipo de problemas, como por ejemplo que `len(cadena)` te puede devolver 4 ó 3 según qué editor hayas usado.

Por ello, desde el momento en que tu programa vaya a tener que manejar textos que puedan incluir caracteres no ascii, lo que debe hacerse es trabajar siempre con Unicode.

En python 2, Unicode es otro tipo más de variable, distinto de `str`. Para meter una cadena en Unicode, debes poner una `u` delante de las comillas. Así:

```
cadena = u'Eñe'
```

En este caso Python codifica cada carácter de la cadena de forma uniforme. Todos requerirán 32 bits (aunque esto es realmente transparente para nosotros). La función `len()` sobre una cadena unicode te dice cuántas letras tiene, no cuántos bytes, por lo que devolverá 3 independientemente de en qué editor lo hayas escrito.

Si tienes una cadena que no forma parte del código fuente del programa sino que ha sido leída del exterior (de un fichero, de un socket, o mediante `raw_input()`), será una cadena `str`, es decir, una secuencia de bytes. Para poder manejarla en tu programa y compararla con otras que sean Unicode, deberás convertirlas también en Unicode. Por ejemplo así:

```
nombre = raw_input("Como te llamas? ")
nombre = unicode(nombre, "utf8")
```

El problema de esta conversión es que, como ves, tienes que especificar el encoding en que se encuentra la cadena `str`. En este ejemplo he puesto `"utf8"`, suponiendo que la terminal desde la que leo el texto usa utf8. Si usara otro *encoding* la conversión podría fallar. Lo mismo si lees de fichero, debes saber en qué *encoding* está el fichero.

Yendo a tu ejemplo. Tienes un código equivalente a éste:

```
cadena = "EÑE"
for letra in cadena:
    if letra == 'E':
        print 'Letra E'
    elif letra == 'Ñ':
        print 'Letra Ñ'
    else:
        print 'Otra letra'  # <-- He añadido esto
```

Como ves, `cadena` es de tipo `str` (pues no lleva `u` delante). Si este código lo escribes desde un editor que use UTF8, la cadena contendrá cuatro bytes según lo antes explicado. Esto implica que el bucle se repetiría *cuatro* veces (como podrás comprobar si lo ejecutas). En cada iteración `letra` será un byte. En ninguna de sus iteraciones se cumplirá que `letra == "Ñ"`, pues  `"Ñ"` son dos bytes según explicamos antes.

Ahora tiene sentido su misteriosa salida:

```
Letra E
Otra letra
Otra letra
Letra E
```

Se arreglaría así:

```
cadena = u"EÑE"
for letra in cadena:
    if letra == u'E':
        print 'Letra E'
    elif letra == u'Ñ':
        print 'Letra Ñ'
    else:
        print 'Otra letra'
```

Aún así tenemos un mix de cadenas normales con cadenas unicode en el que es fácil meter la pata. Python3 simplifica esto haciendo que todas sus cadenas sean Unicode por defecto.

Answer (score 2):

En adición a la respuesta de @abulafia, que explica muy bien por qué pasa esto y como evitarlo, me gustaría añadir que para no tener este tipo de equivocaciones se puede especificar al principio del archivo en un comentario la codificación. Por ejemplo, utf8, que es el por defecto en python 3:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

`utf-8` se puede sustituir por otra codificación si se desea, como `latin-1` o `utf-64`